# Check if TextBox is Empty or not

Tags: vb.net, debugging

I'm currently programming a little login system and I'm trying to prevent users from creating an account with nothing typed into the TextBoxes.
This is my current code for registering an account:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox1.Text = My.Settings.username
    TextBox2.Text = My.Settings.password

    If Trim(TextBox1.Text).Length < 1 AndAlso Trim(TextBox2.Text).Length < 1 Then
        MsgBox("Wrong username or password!")
    ElseIf Trim(TextBox1.Text).Length > 1 AndAlso Trim(TextBox2.Text).Length > 1 Then
        MsgBox("Your account was created!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Create")
        Me.Hide()
        Form1.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```

Somehow, it will always say "Wrong username or password" even if I type something in. How do I make it only respond "Wrong username or password" if the input is nothing?

Edit:
I fixed the code. But how do i make it possible that the person can only login with the information he registered?

Comment: Instead do String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The mystery of "somehow" can be solved using the debugger.  **[Navigating through Code with the Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**.  The issue will pop out quickly.  Also read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Your code is not checking what the use enters in the TextBoxes, it is checking what you have previously stored in `My.Settings`. Also, you need `OrElse` instead of `AndAlso` in your `If` statement, and you can get rid of the `ElseIf` and just use `Else`.

Comment: @Blackwood how do i check the users input?

Comment: Don't overwrite it before you check it. `Trim(TextBox1.Text).Length < 1` is one way of checking if TextBox1 is empty, but use `OrElse` rather than `AndAlso` if you want to check if **either** TextBox1 **or** TextBox2 is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if `My.Settings.username` and `My.Settings.password` have non empty values. You are replacing both text boxes' `Text` properties with those values. You could do something like:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Not String.IsNullOrWhitespace(My.Settings.username) Then
        TextBox1.Text = My.Settings.username
    End If
    If Not String.IsNullOrWhitespace(My.Settings.password) Then
        TextBox2.Text = My.Settings.password
    End If      


    If String.IsNullOrWhitespace(TextBox1.Text) or String.IsNullOrWhitespace(TextBox2.Text) Then
        MsgBox("Wrong username or password!")
...
```

Please note that in your code, you are not evaluating when `TextBox1.Text.Trim().Length = 1` and/or `TextBox2.Text.Trim().Length = 1`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? And as what Emilio mentioned above, please make sure that your My.Settings.username and My.Settings.password are not passing any values.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
   TextBox1.Text = My.Settings.username
   TextBox2.Text = My.Settings.password

   If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) AndAlso String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox2.Text) Then
      MsgBox("Wrong username or password!")
   Else
      MsgBox("Your account was created!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Create")
      Me.Hide()
      Form1.Show()
   End If
End Sub
```