# VB How to limit the Login system on the information used to register?

Tags: vb.net

i have coded a login and a registration system.
If you register an account, you will be sent to the Login window.
In the login window you should type in the username & password you registered.
But instead you could just write something random in, and it would still work.
Is it possible to make a check if the account the user registered was being used, or if something random was input? If so, how?
Thanks

Edit: Just figured out how to add code, here is the login form code:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    My.Settings.username = TextBox1.Text
    My.Settings.password = TextBox2.Text

    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox1.Text) OrElse String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox2.Text) Then
        MsgBox("Wrong username or password!")
    ElseIf TextBox1.Text = My.Settings.username And TextBox2.Text = My.Settings.password Then
        MsgBox("Welcome, you were successfully logged in!")
        Me.Hide()
        Selector.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  There are also many useful tips to writing a good question in the [help].

Comment: You should name your controls.

Comment: Code was added.

Comment: You should not repost the [same question over and over](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47996957/1070452)  That is little improived from before - how can the controls **not** match settings if you just set them to match 1 line earlier

Comment: Don't save the settings until *after* you know the information is correct.

Comment: @LarsTech how do i check if the information is correct?

Comment: Your question is way too broad.  You need a "list" of users, which I think you were trying to get from a file.  Which is fine if you are just trying to learn and play around.  Break down your project into identifiable steps, and google those parts that you need.

Comment: Alright. Yeah im new to this and im just messing around with stuff. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When someone tries to login you should be checking your database (table should have a column for Active) for that User and verifying that the credentials they provided were correct and they are an Active User. If they are good then let them proceed, else show the error to the User and let them keep trying. You have to decide if you want to limit the re-tries and lock the User account if they don't get it within 3 tries. You could put a time-stamp on the record for when it failed and if it has been 30 minutes or more let them try again.

Comment: Where do you get the notion from the question that there is a DataBase involved?

Comment: If there is not one something is really wrong...how else would you keep records? He did say in the question that the User was registering an account...so...

Comment: I haven't included a database yet, im sorry. The account was saved locally on the pc.